# Visitor Hits Counter - Suggested Approach

Tags: php

I was recently brought a challenge from a friend. Thought I'd share it here because I have no good solution.

Say I need a visitor hits count for my website, the count would permanently increase on every visit.

### The Problem

It is considered bad practice to **change the server state with GET requests**. And since I'd like to keep count of the number of users that entered my website, I'll have to store the state somehow.

How would I approach this? Should I break that practice and change the server on GET requests? Or is there some more elaborate scheme I can pull off?

Comment: google analytics's comes to mind.

Comment: @Dagon: That too, but the point is to display it on-site :)

Comment: you are talking about page hits or sessions?

Comment: @DelPedro: Hits, sorry if that wasn't clear, I'll update the question.

Comment: You can pull data from google analytics with http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/

Comment: @Musa but it's not exactly real-time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion you're making is generally true. But here, you want precisely to track if someone made a GET request. So doing this treatment on such requests makes sense!

It's just a bit tricky when using in combination with a caching mechanism. Because the part where you count the visitor can't be in cache, you always need server-side to track the count.

Other solutions include:

- External tools like Google Analytics uses JavaScript with a tracking image (the retrieval of the image is a way to simulate the POST request, but it's just GET anyway), in combination with a cookie to track only unique visitors.
- Log analysis is another alternative. Web servers can write every request in a file, along with other informations (such as IP address, User-Agent). Analyzing the access log can be solution.

[edit] I particularly like the tracking image. Makes both solutions easier.

Comment: How would you deal with the caching issue? Simply add a random GET variable to the "image"?

Comment: Hum. No. Well, why not. But HTTP headers are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

What I do to record visits is use PHP's `auto_prepend_file` or `auto_append_file`. In those files you have something like this:

```
error_reporting(0);
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'visitor_counter', 'password', 'visitors');
$ip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$query = "UPDATE `visits` SET `count` = `count` + 1 WHERE `ip` = '$ip'";
mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I use a shared host, so I have to use a `.htaccess` file like this:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /php/head.php
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Then if you want to show the number of visitors, then in the prepended file, you retrieve the number from the database, set it in a variable, then you can use something like `<div id="visitors"><?php echo $visitors; ?></div>`.

Comment: I record IP addresses and use an IP to location service to make a map of visitors that I display on my website.

Comment: I didn't ask how to do it, I asked whether it's a good idea to change the server state on GET requests. Please read the question.